# Monitoring tool for docker containers

Tags: docker, monitoring, graphite, grafana, docker-container

We have a AWS Server with docker installed and configured. We are running few docker containers and also we want to monitor all the docker containers like **CPU Usage, Memory Usage, Disk Usage, etc**.

Is it possible to monitor docker container remotely and also graphically?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Recommending tools is off topic for SO.

Comment: try with netdata: https://my-netdata.io/

Answer (score 1):

I use a combination of Datadog and a small tool called [Docker Event Monitor](https://bitbucket.org/quaideman/dem) that runs as a container on the Docker host and sends out alerts to Slack, Discord or SparkPost if certain events are triggered. You can configure which events trigger alerts.

Answer (score 0):

For docker monitoring, I recommand telegraf + influxdb + grafana. Telegraf Docker input handle all the things you need : https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/docker

Answer (score 0):

There are some open source components that you can blend together like the previous answer mentioned. cAdvisor and Prometheus + Grafana is another option.

If you are more looking for an integrated commercial solution, have a look at CoScale and its product for [Docker monitoring](https://www.coscale.com/docker-monitoring).

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of tools that are used to system/docker health check like splunk, grafana, graylog, etc.

But **portainer** is an amazing tool that is only designed to use for dockers. Deployment is very simple. You just need to run a docker image. You can check container logs, exec, stats, and many more.

```
docker volume create portainer_data
docker run -d -p 9000:9000 -p 8000:8000 --name portainer --restart always -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v portainer_data:/data portainer/portainer
```

Check the documentation for more info:-
https://portainer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/deployment.html